# MVVM with ZK framework

Tags: mvvm, frameworks, zk, vs-web-application-project

am using MVVM with zk framework for developping a telecom application is it a good framework ?? can anyone share his expierience with me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ZK is good for RAD because it's veiw layer is very easy and things can be done very rapidly. We have developed e-commerce application using ZK and it's good.

Comment: Can you reference some documentation about it?